# Node.js/Express project structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

so I've had strictly a MVC programming background (Laravel, CodeIgniter, Django, etc.) and more and more I'm build bigger projects in Node.js but I'm having a difficult time figuring out a solid way of structuring my project that makes sense...

I've done some research and I love the way J. Cole Morrison does it [here](http://start.jcolemorrison.com/quick-tip-organizing-routes-in-large-express-4-x-apps/) but it makes for extremely fat route files.

The structure is something like

app
-router 
-index.js (your main route def. that imports individual route files)
--routes

This is nice and readable but all of your logic is stuffed in the routes folder which just doesn't make sense (or does it?). I guess I'd expect something more along the lines of seperate controllers that will handle your thinking. Does anyone else have Ideas or structures they use or is this a good way to go?

Comment: Have you considered taking a look at `Sails JS`? an `MVC` framework for `Node.Js`?
http://sailsjs.org/#!

Comment: Actually I have, It's very intriguing. It might be my next step. I do love learning how a language works inside and out before I rely on a framework though

Comment: Node (and other JS packages) have the flexibility to let user decide what structure that they would like to follow.

I Happen to like this one. http://mean.io/#!/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using node.js / express.js in some projects, I have found Kraken's (1.+) structure very useful. It uses folders as part of the routes. Also, it comes with a scaffolding tool, so the mvc structure is easy to keep. This is not the only solution, but it is a good one indeed.

Disclosure: This is copy from [kraken.js](http://krakenjs.com/)

> /config   Application configuration including environment-specific
>   configs
>
> /controllers Routes and logic
>
> /locales Language specific content bundles
>
> /lib Common libraries to be used across your app
>
> /models Models
>
> /public Web resources that are publicly available
>
> /public/templates Server and browser-side templates
>
> /tasks Grunt tasks to be automatically registered by
>   [grunt-config-dir]
>
> /tests Unit and functional test cases
>
> index.js Application entry point